# 560 million page views per month but how many http requests per minute?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, statistics

I have just read an excellent article [StackOverflow Update: 560M Pageviews A Month, 25 Servers, And It's All About Performance](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html).

It left me with a question about what 560 million page views translates to into an average number http requests per minute.

What is the daily average Call Per Minute/Requests Per Minute across the Stack Exchange stack?

I am not asking for someone to divide page views to get at the value (given it really isn't as simple as that given a number of requests can go into serving a single page and a page view doesn't always include AJAX queries).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Nick Craver's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) [blog](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/) (note these are for the Stack Exchange network, not Stack Overflow on its own).

A typical weekday sees 148,084,883 HTTP requests hitting the load balancer. Note that that won't include CDN traffic (for CSS/ JS/ IMG assets), or for images.

148,084,883 / 24 / 60 / 60 = 1713.945405092593 RPS.

Comment: +1 great info thanks - this was from Nov 2013 so I will hold out for a more recent stat - if one exists - if not I will accept.